# Working (part of) an MS Project schedule backwards

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I'm trying to make a portion of my MS Project schedule work backwards, and it's not working quite right. I'm hoping you can help.

I have a schedule where Task 45 ends on 2/1/17. Tasks 46 through 50 are all chained together, Finish-to-Start. I want Task 50 to end on the same day as Task 45 (2/1/17) and for Tasks 46-49 to all start as late as possible but still be done in time to have Task 50 end on the same day as Task 45.

To do this, I've set up Tasks 46-49 to start as late as possible, and for Task 50 to start as early as possible with Tasks 45FF and 49FS as predecessors.

Unfortunately what is happening is that Task 50 is ending on the project's end date, not on the same day as Task 45. It appears that Project is looking at the predecessors for Task 50 and thinking that as long as it ends some time after Task 45 it's ok. What I want it to tell Project that Tasks 45 and 50 must end on the same day. Is there a way to do that without entering in a specific date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have set up should work under most circumstances. My guess is that you have a later task linked to Task 50 through successors that has a Must Finish On date. Try changing the MFO date(s) to Finish No Later Than.

The ALAP tasks will push everything out to meet the MFO date, but won't push out to meet a soft constraint--Finish No Later Than.

Comment: Hi, i have a similar problem and i wanted to clarify something. Have the predecessors for tasks 46-49 as follows:
Task 46: 47sf
Task 47: 48sf
Task 48: 49sf etc

Or is there a smarter way rather than having to SF every later task in order to work backwards? Thanks very much

Comment: 1) It's better to create a new post rather than ask a question in the comments of a post that is a) old, and b) not yours.  2) Don't use SF links. Change the constraint type to As Late As Possible to work backwards from a hard finish (Must Finish On constraint on the last task). Check out [Set the start date or finish date for your project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-start-date-or-finish-date-for-your-project-in-project-desktop-486b5f04-e647-40d9-8298-ba42613ae6d4).

Comment: https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/29593/microsoft-project-using-as-late-as-possible-instead-of-sf-dependencies

If you could have a look, i would really appreciate it. Hope you're having a great wknd.